# Spacy model download issue

Tags: model, nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy 1.3

However, it looks like I cannot download the model now.

```
20/29 : RUN python -m spacy.en.download all
The command '/bin/sh -c python -m spacy.en.download all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: can you try using this: python -m spacy download en 
See if it works, because I tried like this. It worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the download server – this will be fixed asap. (I'm one of the spaCy maintainers btw. Sorry about the inconvenience.)

All models are also attached as archives [to the v1.6 release](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v1.6.0) – so in the meantime, you can always download them manually from there, unzip the archive and place the contained folder in `spacy/data`.

If you don't *have to* use v1.3, I'd also recommend checking out the newer versions and upgrading to spaCy v1.7+. Models are now [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models), which makes the downloading process more transparent and doesn't rely on a separate download server. They're also wrapped as native Python packages, which lets you install them via pip, add them to your project's `requirements.txt` and even `import` them as a module at the top of your file. You can read more about this in the [models documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models).

This makes it easier to manage model dependencies, especially as more models become available. If you're using spaCy 1.8+, you'll be able to use models for English, German, French and Spanish. If you have trained your own models and decide to upgrade, note that you will have to **retrain your models** with the input from the new version. Models trained on spaCy <v1.7 are not compatible with v1.7+.

Comment: Hi Ines, thanks for the detailed answer. I think it is also better to update the Spacy to 1.7+. Because I use docker, if the server is down. It means that the docker build will fail.

Comment: I have just rebuild the docker image. It looks like your guys fix the problem in download server.